# How to resolve NoneType object errors

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to run this code which prints a particular pattern but this error is thrown for line 4
This code runs perfectly on Hackerrank but not on any other online IDE's or Spyder

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'center'


a=int(input("enter a: "))           #line1
b=int(input("enter b=a*3: "))       #line2
for i in range(0,a,2):              #line3
      print('.|.'*i).center(b,'-')  #line4
print("WELCOME").center(b,'-')      #line5
for i in range(a-2,-1,-2):          #line6
      print('.|.'*i).center(b,'-')  #line7
```

Expected output

```
---------.|.---------
------.|..|..|.------
---.|..|..|..|..|.---
-------WELCOME-------
---.|..|..|..|..|.---
------.|..|..|.------
---------.|.---------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what values you're using for inputs, but `center` is a string method and `print` returns a `None` type. You need to apply the `center` method on the string instead:

```py
a=int(input("enter a: "))           
b=int(input("enter b=a*3: "))       
for i in range(0,a,2):              
      print(('.|.'*i).center(b,'-'))
print(("WELCOME").center(b,'-'))      
for i in range(a-2,-1,-2):          
      print(('.|.'*i).center(b,'-'))
```